# Save instant.now() and load is not returning the same precision

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, java-time, java-17

I'm saving an Instant field which is mapped with hibernate (5.5)/jpa (2.2) as `TIMESTAMPTZ` to Postgres, then on tests we need to load it and compare them.
With Java 17.

When saved it was: `expiresAt=2022-10-11T08:06:35.702666317Z`

when I query the data: `expiresAt=2022-10-11T08:06:35.702666Z`

```
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMPTZ", nullable = false)
private Instant expiresAt;
```

This is happening after we migrate to Java 17, and the instantiation, saving and fetching of the data is happening on same JVM (docker).
And this was not happening with Java 11.

Comment: Postgres `timestamp` types  have microsecond resolution per [Date/Time types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).  So the result you see is expected. You will need to truncate/round the timestamp values in Java to the same resolution to get the same result back.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in Hibernate 6, but for Hibernate 5 there is not much that can be done, as the API/SPI changes which are necessary are too big for version 5. Also see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15135 which was the issue as part of which this was fixed.

Comment: this is still happening with hibernate 6, here you can find a minimal example: https://github.com/soasada/lastmodifiedproblem

Comment: Please create a new JIRA issue for this if that is still a problem for you.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue in Hibernate 6, spring data jpa 3.1.x

Comment: Then please create a new JIRA ticket and attach a test case (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) for reproducing the problem.